# How to do non blocking socket reads with Protobuf using C#?

Tags: c#, async-await, protocol-buffers, nonblocking

Lets say I want to do non blocking reads from a network socket.
I can async await for the socket to read x bytes and all is fine.

But how do I combine this with deserialization via protobuf?

Reading objects from a stream must be blocking? that is, if the stream contains too little data for the parser, then there has to be some blocking going on behind the scenes so that the reader can fetch all the bytes it needs.

I guess I can use lengthprefix delimiters and read the first bytes and then figure out how many bytes I have to fetch minimum before I parse, is this the right way to go about it?
e.g. if my buffer is 500 bytes, then await those 500 bytes, and parse the lengthprefix and if the length is more than 500 then wait again, untill all of it is read.

What is the idiomatic way to combine non blocking IO and protobuf parsing?

(I'm using Jon Skeet's implementation right now http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-port/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a general rule, serializers don't often contain a `DeserializeAsync` method, because that is **really really** hard to do (at least, efficiently). If the data is of moderate size, then I would advise to buffer the required amount of data using asynchronous code - and then deserialize when all of the required data is available. If the data is very large and you don't want to have to buffer everything in memory, then consider using a regular synchronous deserialize on a worker thread.

(note that note of this is implementation specific, but if the serializer you are using *does* support an async deserialize: then sure, use that)

Comment: Could you expand more on what's so hard about it? Isn't just replacing every `Read()` with `await ReadAsync()` enough?

Comment: @svick firstly, notice I said "efficiently". Deserialization is often an awful lot of individually simple operations. Creating a Task etc for each of those is inappropriate. Secondly: many serializers make use of meta-programming, which means the generated code also needs to implement this - and note that meta-programming does not always mean "generates c# that gets fed to the compiler". If you had to do everything that "await" does, manually, in IL -you might just go crazy. Crazier, in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `BeginReceive/EndRecieve()` methods to receive your data into a byte buffer (typically 1024 or 2048 bytes). In the `AsyncCallback`, after ensuring that you didn't read -1/0 bytes (end of stream/disconnect/io error), attempt to deserialize the packet with ProtocolBuf.

Your receive callback will be asynchronous, and it makes sense to parse the packet in the same thread as the reading, IMHO. It's the handling that will likely cause the biggest performance hit.

Comment: Well if the message is > buffer.Length , then it will fail and I've wasted CPU cycles on parsing incomplete data.. this has to be handled with length prefixes I guess (?)

Comment: Why would you be sending a message larger than 1024/2048 bytes? Aside from file transfers of course. Implementations I've seen doing this would send the data in 1024/2048 byte chunks and group them by a signalling integer to signal their order; the server would then re-join them on the server side

Comment: Any message carrying a text field could easily break 1024bytes. it seems like an weak approach to build this kind of limitation into the system.