# Does protocol buffer handle nicely end of data on stream

Tags: networking, error-handling, protocol-buffers, blocking, nonblocking

I am totally newbie in c#, .net core 2 and protocol buffers but I have to work with thoses 3 technologies for a personnel project (server/client architecture). I have some questions about serialization/deserialization in multiple message.
I have already see this:
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/techniques#streaming
So I know it's need a special technique. After a little google session I found something about put and pop limits in c++ but I haven't see docs on c#.

I have an another question, does google protocol buffers handle nicely reading ? My sockets are monitored with select so when I want to read my messages (using https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/class/google/protobuf/message-parser#class_google_1_1_protobuf_1_1_message_parser_1a110e5d9bc61837e369e5deb093f59161)
I am not sure how protobuf will stop reading (I don't want to read beyond the data available on the socket because it will make my server blocking...)
Does it manage it ? Thank you...

Comment: protobuf doesn't handle message boundarys at all. You'd need to implement message splitting yourself.

Comment: Edit: I found this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21232689/how-to-do-non-blocking-socket-reads-with-protobuf-using-c#21232848 looks awesome, thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standalone protobufs aren't delimited in any way - they don't encode their length and have no fixed start nor end.

But the API gives you some tools for sending and storing multiple messages - specifically, you can use [WriteDelimitedTo()](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/class/google/protobuf/message-extensions#class_google_1_1_protobuf_1_1_message_extensions_1a99a4de2ce4de5bc1da1e1f5c367f4c7c) to write multiple protobufs to some output, and then read them using [parseDelimitedFrom()](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/class/google/protobuf/message-parser-t-#class_google_1_1_protobuf_1_1_message_parser_3_01_t_01_4_1a4de4899d9b5b8fd09587cccf59a0100c)

Comment: Thank you for giving me the correct method about how write correctly the data length. But does I have to manage the reading part ? If Sockets.Select () told me "its okay to read from this socket" and then I tried parsedDelimitedFrom() how much it will read ? More than the data available on the socket ?

Comment: Read the documentation. It says "The stream is expected to contain a length and then the data. Only the amount of data specified by the length will be consumed. " So WriteDelimitedTo prefixes the protobuf with its length, and `parseDelimitedFrom` reads the correct number of bytes.

Comment: Yep, this is what I see after all. I think I need to find a way to determine if there is enough data on the socket before parseDelimitedFrom... thank you.